# Вход в роутер через python

Tags: python, http, requests, xmlhttprequest, роутер

Всем привет, хочу сделать парсер своего роутера. Но через requests не могу войти ошибка 401.
Как я понял нужно использовать HTTP запросы. Не знаю как решить данную проблему надеюсь на вашу помощь) Вот как выглядит окно со входом в роутер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При показе "как выглядит окно со входом в роутер"  единственное что я вам могу посоветовать использовать селенимум

Comment: Кстати не плохой вариант, я про селениум вообще забыл))

Comment: Самое обидно что я не могу войти через selenium как и через requests, т.к поля для ввода логина и пароля это не элементы css/html(

Comment: "Но через requests не могу войти ошибка 401. " выложите ваш код.